# Update AnnotationView after/during zoom

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I need to change the `centerOffset` property of an `AnnotationView` when the zoomlevel changed. I don't want to remove and add the `Annotations` again.

So how can I access and update the `AnnotationViews` after zooming?

Any ideas on this?

Best Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to use these `MKMapView` methods :

```
- (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect // iOS4.2+ only!
```

to retrieve visible Annotations, then use :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

To get the corresponding view (should never return nil if first function does it job correctly)

Then I guess changing `centerOffset` should do the job, (plus maybe some `-[UIView setNeedsDisplay/Layout]` to force a redraw)

Changing centerOffset depending on zoomLevel sounds strange, but I guess you have your reasons :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've used the mapView.annotations property to get the annotations (<4.2 depl. target). For updating the annotations I needed to reassign the coordinate.. `setNeedsDisplay` etc didn't work: `CLLocationCoordinate2D foo = annotation.coordinate;
[annotation setCoordinate:foo];`

Reason for changing the offset during zoomlevel: we have a map overlay with 3d buildings on it and wanted to show the annotations on the roofs for visual experience. The client can provide an offset on backend-side. Because of the different size after zoom-in/out the offset needed to be recalculated.

Comment: ah I see, I knew there was a reason to this, thanks for feedback :)